# How to skip 0 th position value from array sort in android?

Tags: android, arrays, sorting

How to skip 0th position value from array sorting.

This is my array with values

```
ss = new String[4]; 
ss[0]= "Select"; 
ss[1]="Banana"; 
ss[2]="Apple"; 
ss[3]="Cat";
```

I need to skip 0th position("Select" text should be the same position) and sort the values.

I want output like this below.

```
ss[0]= "Select"; 
ss[2]="Apple"; 
ss[1]="Banana"; 
ss[3]="Cat";
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy original array to an array of size [original array size - 1]
2. Sort the second array
3. Fill the original array (starting from index 1) with values from second array

Try this out

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Stack {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[] ss = {"Select", "Banana", "Apple", "Cat"};

        String[] sp = new String[ss.length - 1];

        System.arraycopy(ss, 1, sp, 0, sp.length);

        Arrays.sort(sp);

        for (int i = 1; i < sp.length; i++) {
            ss[i] = sp[i - 1];
        }

        for (String s : ss) {
            System.out.println(s);
        } 
    }
}
```

Output

> Select
>   Apple
>   Banana
>   Cat

Or you can use `Array.copyOfRange()`. I'm not familiar with Android, so not sure if it supports `System` class.

```
 String[] sz = Arrays.copyOfRange(ss, 1, ss.length - 1);

 Arrays.sort(sz);

 ....
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this cod working fine. but i want show the array values in android spinner 

ss[0]= "Select"; 
ss[2]="Apple"; 
ss[1]="Banana"; 
ss[3]="Cat";

Comment: Sorry but I don't know Android very well.

Answer (score 0):

This really doesn't solve the problem, it just dodges it, but you could:

> ss = 1;

If you're going to loop over it, It won't go back to "0"